# Issues with building and running docker containers in GCP VM Instance

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to build a docker image from a docker file in GCP VM instance.
When I am running the docker build command I am receiving the following error

**`toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit`**

My docker file is as follows :

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV APP_HOME app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .
RUN pip install Flask google-auth google-cloud-storage numpy datetime pandas sklearn

ENV PORT 8080
CMD ["python", "app_hello.py"]
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: I think you're being impacted by this: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/mitigating-the-impact-of-new-docker-hub-pull-request-limits You may be able to pull the Python image from Google's mirror: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling-cached-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared the issue is with pulling the docker image for it.

As stated in the [link](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits) :

> The rate limits of 100 container image requests per six hours for anonymous usage, and 200 container image requests per six hours for free Docker accounts are now in effect. Image requests exceeding these limits will be denied until the six hour window elapses.

To overcome docker hub pull rate limit refer to [link](https://container-registry.com/posts/overcome-docker-hub-rate-limit/).

Also as suggested by @DazWilkin try  to pull the Python image from [Google's mirror](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling-cached-images).

For additional information refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902874/kubernetes-container-runtime-network-not-ready).

Comment: With the approach of Google's mirror , the issue is intermittent .